# akka-http crashes when adding slf4j/logback

Tags: scala, sbt, akka, akka-http, akka-stream

I have a working `akka-http` application. Now I tried adding logging via slf4j and logback and my application crashes.

**build.sbt**

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http" % "10.0.7",
  "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.2.3",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-slf4j" % "2.5.2"
)
```

**application.conf**

```
akka {
  loggers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger"]
  loglevel = "DEBUG"
  logging-filter = "akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLoggingFilter"
}
```

**logback.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration debug="true">

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

**error:**

> Detected java.lang.NoSuchMethodError error, which MAY be caused by
>   incompatible Akka versions on the classpath. Please note that a given
>   Akka version MUST be the same across all modules of Akka that you are
>   using, e.g. if you use akka-actor [2.5.2 (resolved from current
>   classpath)] all other core Akka modules MUST be of the same version.
>   External projects like Alpakka, Persistence plugins or Akka HTTP etc.
>   have their own version numbers - please make sure you're using a
>   compatible set of libraries.
>
> Uncaught error from
>   thread [my-system-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6] shutting down JVM
>   since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled for
>   ActorSystem[my-system] java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   akka.actor.ActorCell.addFunctionRef(Lscala/Function2;)Lakka/actor/FunctionRef;

According to the message, it's a compatibility issue. How do I find out which versions of `akka-http` and `akka-slf4j` are compatible (except trying out)?

On a side note, since it's a similar problem: I want to add `akka-stream`. However, using the newest versions of `akka-http` and `akka-stream` gives me eviction warnings in sbt. Same quesion as above: how do I find out which versions to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately `akka-http` is versioned separately from the rest of `akka` and the newest version of it does not necessarily use the newest version of `akka`. In case of `akka-http` version `10.0.7` the compatible `akka` version is `2.4.18`. You can see it [here](https://github.com/akka/akka-http/blob/v10.0.7/project/Dependencies.scala#L24). This means that you need to drop to that version in `akka-slf4j` dependency to run the application without problems.